# FB.api() object type as a variable

Tags: facebook, api, object, types, facebook-opengraph

I have written the code below:

function processLWO(lwo,type)
{
    FB.api('me/'+lwo,
           'post',
           {shoe :'<%=sItemURL%>',object :'<%=sItemURL%>'},
            function (response) 
            {
                //code
            }
          );
}

My problem is with the following line of code:

```
//Code that works - Code A
shoe :'<%=sItemURL%>',object :'<%=sItemURL%>'

//Code I want to use - Code B
type.toString():'<%=sItemURL%>'
```

Code A works but I want to implement Code B because it is more flexible however Code B returns a Javascript error stating the original function that lead to this function is undefined. I understand type.toString() should be a Facebook object (for example, shoe or object) but if type.toString() is processed and returns a value then it would be evaluated as a valid object type.

Any suggestions how to solve this? Code A is just so lazy/stupid....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var params = {};
params[type] = <%=sItemURL%>'
FB.api('/me/' + lwo, 'POST', params, ...
```

Comment: So what's wrong with this:

    type.toString():'<%=sItemURL%>'

Why does 

    var params = {};
    params[varPassedToFunction] = <%=sItemURL%>'
    FB.api('/me/' + lwo, 'POST', params,...

work and the code I tried didn't work?

Comment: See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-A.3, the `PropertyName` section.